Partition of a vertex set into two subsets and the upper bound of the total number of edges in their vertex-induced subgraphs
Let $G=(V,E)$ be a regular graph of degree 5 and $n$ vertices, $\{V_1,V_2\}$ be a partition of $V,$ and $H_1=(V_1,E_1),H_2=(V_2,E_2)$ be vertex-induced subgraphs. I want to prove that for every even number $n\ge6,$ we can always partition $V$ into $V_1$ and $V_2$ such that $|E_1|+|E_2| \le n.$
It's clearly true when $n=6,$ just put any three vertices in $V_1$ and the remaining in $V_2$, then each induced subgraph is a triangle, so $|E_1|=|E_2|=3$ and $|E_1|+|E_2| \le n=6.$

If $E_{1,2}$ denotes the remaining edges, then what you want to prove is that $|E_{1,2}|\ge3n/2 = 3m/5$, where $m=5n/2$ is the total number of edges. Essentially, this means you want to show that the maximum cut size is at least $3m/5$. The trivial lower bound is $m/2$, so there’s no immediate contradiction.

You might want to say that they are induced subgraphs. Otherwise, the inequality is trivially satisfied by the trivial subgraphs.

Any $d$-regular graph is $(d+1)$-colorable. And any $2k$-colorable graph has maximum cut of size at least $km/(2k-1)$, where $m$ is the number of edges. See this post for a proof of the second assertion: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1918997/715329
Therefore, any $5$-regular graph has maximum cut of size at least $3m/5$, which is equivalent to the statement you want to prove as I explained in the comments.
